# working with multiprocessing using map() in python code in bigdata

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, fault-tolerance, bigdata

I'm trying to get some values(which I get using extract function) from urls which are stored in data.file and there are about 3000000 url links in the file. here is my code snippet,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(10)
revenuelist = p.map(extract, data.file )
```

But the problem is, due to internet connection, this is code runs again if there connection problem. How do I add fault tolerance to my code(i:e store intermediate result, to avoid repetition of doing same task).

Comment: If the job is fetching urls, consider using threads instead of processes.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is using a file to store your current status.  Use try...finally to handle fails:

```
with open(FILENAME) as f:
    current = int(f.read() or 0)

if current:
    skip_lines(current)

try:
    with Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.imap(extract, data.file)
        for result in results:
            do_something(result)
            current += 1
finally:
    with open(FILENAME, "w") as f:
        f.write(str(current))
```

See also: ['concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) (much cooler than multiprocessing.Pool).

A better solution would be using a database to completely track your progress, and/or use a better task queue (for example, [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)) to execute your jobs.

Comment: This is kinda ugly, and that global state kills the benefits of `map`. The OP can easily transform `extract` into a total function with an optional return value and use a recursive `map/filter/reduce` strategy to separate successful and failed calls to repeat calculations for the failed (empty) cases.

Comment: I agree this is ugly :-) Using a task queue and a database is much neater - however, if this is  some kind of batch process he runs only once, and just needs a "restart where failed" feature, this should be good enough :-)

Comment: What do you mean in *"global state kills the benefits of map"?* the sole purpose of the map here is to use n processes instead of 1 (for 3000000 jobs), and `imap` should be good enough here.

Comment: `imap` is usually several times slower than `map`. If the target function is relatively light, this might affect performance significantly.

Comment: Well, the question above clearly does not need to use `map()`, since it considers tasks already run as done :-)